# How to get the number of li's in a ul using mootools?

Tags: mootools

Can anyone provide me with the code to get the number of li's in a ul list please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mootools, a HTML collection has a normal `length` property:

```
var lis = document.getElements("ul li"), numLis = lis.length;
```

this also works as `$$("ul li")` or `document.id("menu").getElements("ul li");` or even `document.getElements("#menu ul li")` or `document.getElements("ul#menu li")` as various ways to narrow it down / add specificity, dependent on your dom - the higher up the dom tree you are, the better.

Comment: It should be mentioned that any code in answer above would count all lis, even in nested lists, if such is present. Be careful :) Use ul>li selector to count direct children.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well: `ul.getChildren().length`